# Php array - lost some values

Tags: php, arrays

I tried to insert some values into an array, but I don't know why I lost some values of them

This is the code I am using right now:

```
<pre><code>
<?php
include 'config/connections.php';
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM table"; 
$result = $db->query($SQL) or die("Couldn't execute 
query.".mysqli_error($db)); 
$numresult=$result->num_rows;
for ($i=0; $i<$numresult; $i++)
{
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();  
    $c['id']   = 'H'.$i;
    $c['start']= date("Y-m-d");
    $a[$i]   = $c;
    for ($j=1; $j<4; $j++)
    {
        $c['id']   = 'H'.$i;
        $c['start']= date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+".$j." days"));
       array_push($a,$c);
    }
}
echo json_encode($a);
?>
</pre></code>
```

Output:

```
    [{"id":"H0","start":"2015-05-13"},
    {"id":"H1","start":"2015-05-13"},
    {"id":"H2","start":"2015-05-13"},
    {"id":"H3","start":"2015-05-13"},
    {"id":"H0","start":"2015-05-17"},
    {"id":"H1","start":"2015-05-14"},
    {"id":"H1","start":"2015-05-15"},
    {"id":"H1","start":"2015-05-16"},
    {"id":"H1","start":"2015-05-17"},
    {"id":"H2","start":"2015-05-14"},
    {"id":"H2","start":"2015-05-15"},
    {"id":"H2","start":"2015-05-16"},
    {"id":"H2","start":"2015-05-17"},
    {"id":"H3","start":"2015-05-14"},
    {"id":"H3","start":"2015-05-15"},
    {"id":"H3","start":"2015-05-16"},
    {"id":"H3","start":"2015-05-17"}]
```

I lost some values from array:

```
 
    {"id":"H0","start":"2015-05-14"}, 
    {"id":"H0","start":"2015-05-15"}, 
    {"id":"H0","start":"2015-05-16"}
```

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated!Thanks!

Comment: There is an syntax error on line with `$c['start']= date('Y-m-d", strtotime("+".$j." days"));` It shoulld be `"Y-m-d"`.

Answer (score 2):

On the first loop iteration, `$a[0]` is created and then the second for, adds 3 elements to the `$a` array, so `$a[1]` to `$a[4]` are created.

On the second external for iteration, `$a[1]` is overwritten and the inner for adds `$a[5]` to `$a[7]`.

The third external for iteration overwrites `$a[2]` and so on.

You can do what you want like this:

```
<?php
include 'config/connections.php';
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM table"; 
$result = $db->query($SQL) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysqli_error($db)); 
$numresult=$result->num_rows;
$a = array();
for ($i=0; $i<$numresult; $i++)
{
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();  
    for ($j=0; $j<4; $j++)
    {
        $c['id']   = 'H'.$i;
        $c['start']= date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+".$j." days"));
       array_push($a,$c);
    }
}
echo json_encode($a);
?>
```

Comment: thank you, i have tried your suggestion but it still do not work

Comment: @Candra You could also keep your code and change `$a[$i] = $c;` in your first for loop with `array_push($a, $c);`

Comment: it has worked, thank you axxis you have saved my life